# What is the perimeter of a sector?

Tags: geometry, circles

I don't understand this.

[image]

So we have:

\begin{align}
r &= 12 \color{gray}{\text{ (radius of circle)}} \\
d &= 24 \text{ (r}\times2) \color{gray}{\text{ (diameter of circle)}} \\
c &= 24\pi \text{ (}\pi\times d) \color{gray}{\text{ (circumference of circle)}} \\
a &= 144\pi \text{ (}\pi\times r^2) \color{gray}{\text{ (area of circle)}}
\end{align}

And we have:

\begin{align}
ca &= 60^\circ \color{gray}{\text{ (Central Angle of sector)}} \\
ratio &= \frac{60}{360} = \frac{1}{6} \color{gray}{\text{ (ratio of ca to circle angle which is 360 degrees)}}
\end{align}

So now we can calculate:

\begin{align}
al = \frac{1}{6} \times 24\pi &= 4\pi \color{gray}{\text{ (arc length of SECTOR = ratio X circumference of circle)}}
sa &= \frac{1}{6} \times 144per = 24\pi \color{gray}{\text{ (sector area = ratio X area of circle)}}
\end{align}

So my question is: What is meant by the perimeter of a Sector. Is it the arch length or the are of a Sector? And what is $24 + 4\pi$?

Comment: "Perimeter" always means length, not area.

Comment: @AndreasBlass: so perimeter of a sector = arc length of a sector? Than why + r X 2?

Comment: @Jawad. Because the sector has also two sides equal to radius.

Comment: @AndreasBlass : Thanks mate

Comment: @arbautjc : Thanks man

Comment: The correct transliteration for the Greek letter $\pi$ is "pi". not "pie".

Comment: MathJax, please. Not code blocks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The perimeter of the sector includes the ***length*** of the radius $\times 2$, as well as the ***arc length***. So the perimeter is the length "around" the *entire sector*, the length "around" a slice of pizza, which includes it's edges and its curved arc.

The **arc length** is just the curved portion of the circumference, the **sector permimeter** is the length of line $\overline{AC} = r$ plus the length of line $\overline{BC} = r$, plus the length of the arc ${AOC}$.

The circumference of the circle is the total arc length of the circle.

Length is one-dimensional, the length of a line wrapped around the circle. Area is two dimensional; All of what's *inside* the circle.

Comment: sorry but the perimeter of a circle = circumference of the circle and should not the permimeter of a sector = arc length of the sector?

Comment: @Jawad. Just a question of convention (in the same vein: for area of a cylinder, do you count the two disks?), but it appears the usual convention is counting the radius (see [here](http://mathcentral.uregina.ca/QQ/database/QQ.09.07/h/sara3.html) for example). Anyway it would be useless to have another name for arc length.

Comment: No, they are including the distance around the entire sector, the length "around" a slice of pizza, which includes more than just the outer arc length. The arc length is just the curved portion of the circumference, the sector permimeter is the length line $AC$ plus the length of line $BC$ plus the length of the arc $AOC$.

Comment: so the perimeter of a CIRCLE = circumference of that circle BUT the perimeter of a SECTOR = arc length of that circle + r X 2? Right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. That's correct.

Comment: You're welcome, Jawad!

Comment: just a quicki as an after thought. is not 24 + 4pei = 28pie?

Comment: No, $24\pi + 4\pi = 28\pi$ but $24 + 4 \pi \neq 28\pi$

Comment: great. thanks again

Comment: @amWhy: nice feedback and answer! +1

Answer (score -1):

perimeter of the sector is the sum of the lengths of all its boundaries.thus the perimeter of the sector is L+2r units.

Comment: Your answer could be clarified by specifying what those boundaries are.  In particular, you should indicate how your formula leads to the correct answer.

Answer (score -1):

$\frac{\theta}{360}\times 2\pi (r) + 2r$
That would be the length of the arc in the first part and twice the radius in the second part.

Comment: Welcome to this site! The question you just answered is rather old and already has perfectly good answers, to which your post doesn't seem to add much.  More value to the site would be added by answering unanswered questions, or providing answers with significantly new information.