# Is the value of $\pi$ in 2d the same in 3d?

Tags: circles, 3d, pi

I am starting with my question with the note "Assume no math skills". Given that, all down votes are welcomed. (At the expense of better understanding of course!)

Given my first question: [What is meant by the perimeter of a Sector](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/395820/what-is-a-perimeter-of-a-sector)

1. Why is the value of $\pi$ not exactly $3$? why is it $3.14$.......... or a fraction $\frac{22}{7}$?
2. Is the value of $\pi$ of $3.14$... or $\frac{22}{7}$ the same as for $3$ dimensions?

Comment: http://projectpi.sourceforge.net/2d3d4d_o.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by the value of $ \pi $ for 3 dimensional applications. $ \pi $ is a constant value - it is always equal to $ 3.1415 \ldots $.

Of course formulas don't always translate the same from 2 dimensional to 3 dimensional. For example, the area of a circle is $ \pi r^2 $ but the volume contained within a sphere is $ \frac{4\pi}{3} r^3 $. You could almost say that $ \pi $ in 2 dimensional geometry is analogous to $ \frac{4\pi}{3} $ but then this causes fault in other places with $ \pi $, such as surface area.

Comment: it s not true that $\pi$is always a constant, the value of $pi$ depends on number of things; for example to see how $\pi$ could be equal to 42 look at this : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/254620/pi-in-arbitrary-metric-spaces

Comment: Area of a sphere is not $\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3$. This is the volume of a ball. Area of a sphere is $4\pi r^2$.

Comment: You're right, I misspoke. I forgot to switch terminology between the two cases.

Answer (score 5):

There are several ways to [define](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi) $\pi$, but whichever you choose it is a number that happens to be irrational (it's not equal to any fraction, although some fractions are close).  It does represent the ratio between a circle's circumference and diameter for any  circle (but not for spheres, squares, or other shapes).

With regards to your first question, a sector is a part of a circle, like a slice of pie (the food).  Its perimeter consists of a round bit on the outside, and two straight bits toward the center.